# python - BeautifulSoup and requests does not produce expected results with .findAll()

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.5

I have been writing a piece of code that will retrieve a list of items and their corresponding prices from the Steam Marketplace (for the game Unturned). I am using BeautifulSoup (bs4) and requests library. This is my code so far:

```
for page_num in range(1,10):
website = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=304930#p'+str(page_num)+'_popular_desc'
r = requests.get(website)
doc = r.text.split('\n')
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(doc), "html.parser")

names = soup.findAll("span", { "class" : "market_listing_item_name" })
for item in range(len(names)):
    items.append(names[item].contents[0])

costs = soup.findAll("span", { "class" : "normal_price" })
for cost in range(len(costs)):
    prices.append(costs[cost].contents[0])
```

Expected Output:

```
Festive Gift Present :  $0.32 USD
Halloween Gift Present :  $0.26 USD
Carbon Fiber Mystery Box :  $0.47 USD
Festive Hat :  $1.67 USD
Nuclear Matamorez :  $0.39 USD
... and so on
```

The problem with this code is, it is only getting the names of the first page. If I type the URL manually with different numbers in place of *page_num* it changes the page, and also the HTML document changes. However, the code doesn't seem to get the results from the second page and so on. *requests* is fetching the correct URL each time, but the HTML doc returns the same?

Comment: Page 2, 3, etc, are requested via ajax (or similar), so the source code isn't present when you first load the page.

Comment: You could also try to use selenium + phantomjs. This, together with a sleep() function would also ensure that the data is loaded correctly and can be scraped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 2, 3, etc, are requested via `ajax` (or similar), so the source code isn't present when you first load the page. To bypass this we can sniff the `ajax` url and parse the source directly, in this case, `json` encoded, i.e:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
output = ""
items =[]
prices =[]
for page_num in range(0,100, 10): #
    start = page_num
    count = page_num + 10

    url = urlopen("http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start={}&count={}&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=popular&sort_dir=desc&appid=304930".format(start, count))
    jsonCode = json.loads(url.read())
    output += jsonCode['results_html']

soup = BeautifulSoup(output, "html.parser")

names = soup.findAll("span", { "class" : "market_listing_item_name" })
for item in range(len(names)):
    items.append(names[item].contents[0])

costs = soup.findAll("span", { "class" : "normal_price" })
for cost in range(len(costs)):
    if "Starting at" not in costs[cost].contents[0]: # we just get the first price
        prices.append(costs[cost].contents[0])



print items
[u'Festive Gift Present', u'Halloween Gift Present', u'Hypertech Timberwolf', u'Holiday Scarf', u'Chill Honeybadger', etc...] 
print prices
[u'$0.34 USD', u'$0.28 USD', u'$1.77 USD', u'$0.31 USD', u'$0.65 USD', etc...]
```

---

**PS:** Steam will temporary ban your ip after ~50 requests

Comment: Yep, found that out. They temporarily block your connection for a few minutes. Thanks for the help.